# Spring constant for "spring.config.location" system property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In each example that I can see on the internet, strings are used for system property names instead of using [Spring pre-defined constants](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/constant-values.html#org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.CONFIG_LOCATION_PROPERTY).

Is that a bad practice to use for example `ConfigFileApplicationListener.CONFIG_LOCATION_PROPERTY` instead of `String s = "spring.config.location"` in the code when I work with system properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a constant such as `CONFIG_LOCATION_PROPERTY` is visible to your code (i.e., it's declared `public`), then it's part of the public API, and you are as free to use it as any other public API member. (Note that whether you *should* be manipulating these instead of letting the framework do its job and using the established hooks is a different question.)

In general, the documentation uses the constant values because the input is coming from configuration files, the CLI, or the environment where the configuring user needs to know what keys to set.